# Vue.js in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, javascript-controller

I am trying out my first development with Vue.js in Apex page.

I am doing the first example of navigation Menu from here but getting error as below.

**Error:**

> Attribute name "v-on:click.prevent" associated with an element type "nav" must be followed by the ' = ' character
>   Error Error: Attribute name "v-on:click.prevent" associated with an element type "nav" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

https://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/5-practical-examples-for-learning-vue-js

Here is my markup:

```
<apex:page controller="GICBPToolVue" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.navcss}"/>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.5/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var demo = new Vue({

        // A DOM element to mount our view model.
        el: '#main',

        // This is the model.
        // Define properties and give them initial values.
        data: {
            active: 'home'
        },

        // Functions we will be using.
        methods: {
            makeActive: function(item){
                // When a model is changed, the view will be automatically updated.
                this.active = item;
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
    <html>
    <div id="main">

        <!-- The navigation menu will get the value of the "active" variable as a class. -->

        <!-- To stops the page from jumping when a link is clicked 
            we use the "prevent" modifier (short for preventDefault). -->

        <nav v-bind:class="active" v-on:click.prevent>

            <!-- When a link in the menu is clicked, we call the makeActive method, 
            defined in the JavaScript Vue instance. It will change the value of "active". -->

            <a href="#" class="home" v-on:click="makeActive('home')">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="projects" v-on:click="makeActive('projects')">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="services" v-on:click="makeActive('services')">Services</a>
            <a href="#" class="contact" v-on:click="makeActive('contact')">Contact</a>
        </nav>

        <!-- The mustache expression will be replaced with the value of "active".
             It will automatically update to reflect any changes. -->

        <p>You chose <b>{{active}}</b></p>
    </div>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualforce requires that attributes have a value and are not just used as markers (i.e. the page has to be [well-formed XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document)).

To accomplish this you can add an empty string value e.g.:

```
v-on:click.prevent=""
```

which hopefully will not break Vue.